# How to load image using AsyncImage in jetpack compose with GrayScale transformation?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, coil

I am unable to achieve the grayscale transformation.

Current code to load Image.

```
AsyncImage(
    model = ImageRequest.Builder(LocalContext.current)
        .data(url)
        .crossfade(true)
        .build(),
    contentDescription = "",
    contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
    modifier = Modifier
        .size(44.dp)
        .clip(CircleShape),
)
```

The code I found for GrayScale transformation uses `rememberImagePainter` which is deprecated.

How to achieve this using `rememberAsyncImagePainter` or `AsyncImage`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can apply the **`colorFilter`** attribute:

```
val matrix = ColorMatrix()
matrix.setToSaturation(0F)

AsyncImage(
    model = ImageRequest.Builder(LocalContext.current)
        .data(url)
        .crossfade(true)
        .build(),
    contentDescription = "",
    contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
    modifier = Modifier
        .size(44.dp)
        .clip(CircleShape),
    colorFilter = ColorFilter.colorMatrix(matrix)
)
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, thanks!